# For-loop is not cycling through the length of a list

Tags: r, for-loop, rselenium

I am trying to download a bulk of csv files from google trends using rselenium. I have a list of inputs which I would like to search for and then have their corresponding csv files downloaded.

Now whilst the code works fine in initiating the process, the loop seemingly does not cycle to the second (and further) inputs along the length of the list. Meanwhile, the code for step 2 is working fine, although this is problematic as now I am downloading the same csv file over and over again.

```
input <- list("AAC", "AAN", "AAOI")

for (i in 1:length(input)){

  #step 1: input search query
  webElem1 <- remDr$findElement("class name", "ng-pristine")
  Sys.sleep(2)
  webElem1$sendKeysToElement(input[i])
  webElem1$sendKeysToElement(list(key = 'enter'))
  Sys.sleep(2)

  #step 2: click download CSV
  webElem2 <- remDr$findElement("class name", "widget-actions-item")
  Sys.sleep(2)
  webElem2$clickElement()

}
```

Please excuse me if I may have missed out on something obvious here, as you might guess I am extremely new to all this. It is also worth mentioning that I have done extensive searching for a similar issue, with no luck.

Comment: The issue is not with the loop, it's to do with how you access elements. I suspect it's not going to 2nd iteration because waiting on one of the lines in step 1. Can you post how you create the webdriver and the URL you use?

Comment: Thanks for your help Lakshitha. I revised my code after you pointed out where the error might be and I got it to work.